# Transparency in a BS3 Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar in my BS3 Page, and I want the `.navbar-collapse` to appear `transparent` to go with my gradient. And when on mobile devices, I want the `.navbar-header` to have a `background-color` of `#XXXXXX`. I've tried the usual, `background-color: transparent`, but that does not seem to work. Here's all my code so far.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".navbar-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "transparent");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Titillium Web", Montserrat, "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: initial;
}

.kn-hydrogen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 50%;
  background: #badecb; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #badecb); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #badecb, #9ba970); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #badecb, #9ba970); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #badecb, #9ba970); /* Standard syntax */
}

/*BS3*/

.navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  border-radius: none;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-header {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #88ddb3;
}
.navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover {background-color: #88ddb3;}

.navbar-collapse {border-top:none;}
```

```html
<div class="kn-hydrogen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand">Kn</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href=#>Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href=# class="kn-tennesium">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

To go over it,

1. How do you make `.navbar-collapse` transparent on desktops?
2. How do you make `.navbar-header` have a color #XXXXXX on mobile?

Comment: use mediaquery and set background none in kn-hydrogen and set navbar default background as transparent

Comment: @HamimAlMahdiRussell that'd destroy my gradient. I want to keep my Gradient.